# place textinput at the center of the page

Tags: html, shiny

Is there a way to place the textinput at the center of the page. I created a div with style. But buttons are getting aligned to center except textinput. Can anyone help me?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    div(id = "hp", style = "text-align-last : center"
        ,actionButton("history", "Back To history"), br()
        ,textInput("moddname", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name")
        ,actionButton("next1", "Next")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
        useShinyjs(),
        # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
        div(id = "hp", style = "text-align-last : center"
            ,actionButton("history", "Back To history"), br()
            ,div(
                style = "display: inline-block; margin-top: 10px;",
                textInput("moddname", label = NULL, placeholder = "Name")
            ), br()
            ,actionButton("next1", "Next")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]